# Make the async pipe update the view in Angular 2

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe

The component seen below would display a list of events in the template upon initialization (`ngOnInit()`). However, when the `addEvent()` is invoked, the view will not be updated. Why is this the case?

How can I make the view to be updated whenever I publish new data to a data store that's used to populate the observable property (`events: Observable<Event[]>`)?

```
@Component({
    template:
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let event of events | async"
{{ event.title }}
</li>
</ul>
<button (click)="addEvent()">Add event</button>

})
export class EventCenterListComponent implements OnInit {
    events: Observable<Event[]>;

    constructor(
        private eventsService: EventsService,
    ) {}


    ngOnInit() {
        this.events = return this.eventsService.getEvents();
    }

    addEvent() {
        this.eventsService.createEvent('New event'); <--this would add one event to the data source
        this.events = this.eventsService.getEvents(); <-- that reassignment would not be seen in the template
    }
}
```

I've seen that many tutorials, including Angulat's official tutorial convert the Observable into a plain array and then `push` new values into the array, e.g.:

```
heroes: Hero[];

addHero(name: string) {
  this.heroService.create(name)
                   .subscribe(
                     hero  => this.heroes.push(hero), <-- that would work 
                     error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

But is the above really necessary? Cannot I operate directly on observables and have the view updated?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, better not to subscribe in the component.

Here's one idea. The events service keeps a private array of events, and fires a subject every time it changes. The component can use the async pipe so that its view is updated whenever that subject fires.

```
@Injectable()
export class EventsService {
  private events: Event[] = [];

  private eventsSubject = new Subject<Event[]>();
  private _events$ = this.eventsSubject.asObservable();

  createEvent(title: string) {
    const newEvent: Event = {title};
    this.events = [...this.events, newEvent];
    this.eventsSubject.next(this.events);
  }

  getEvents$() {
    return this._events$;
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let event of events | async">{{ event.title }}</li>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="addEvent()">Add event</button>`
})
export class EventCenterListComponent {
  events: Observable<Event[]>;

  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) {
    this.events = eventsService.getEvents$();
  }

  addEvent() {
    this.eventsService.createEvent('New event');
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

New idea from a closer reading of your question. Assuming EventService works like this:

```
createEvent(title: string): Observable<void> // post one new event to server
getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> // get list of events from server
```

...And you simply want to refetch the list of the events after posting a new one, then implement EventCenterListComponent like this:

```
export class EventCenterListComponent {
  events: Observable<Event[]>;

  private newEventSubject = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(eventsService: EventsService) {
    const eventWasCreated$ = this.newEventSubject.mergeMap(title =>
      eventsService.createEvent(title));

    const shouldRefresh$ = eventWasCreated$.startWith(undefined);

    this.events = shouldRefresh$.switchMap(() =>
      eventsService.getEvents());

    // optional, if you are going to subscribe to `events` in more
    // than one place:
    this.events = this.events.share();
  }

  addEvent() {
    this.newEventSubject.next('New event');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for presenting an alternative. However, I'd rather avoid applying this approach because it makes an HTTP service stateful. On top of that there might be thousands of events that will always be kept in memory, which I think would be sub-optimal.

Comment: @luqo33 ok I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I updated my answer with a totally different solution.